# Translation and rotation axes not locked

Tags: physics

I'm designing a **2D** rigid body physics orthographic animation in Blender Game. It's simply a cube falling on and bouncing off a surface (first picture). The camera (in orthographic mode) is pointed parallel to the Y-axis. To this purpose, I locked the Y translation, as well as the X and Z rotation of the falling cube. So if all works well, all you should ever see of that cube is its camera facing face. However, apparently, **it doesn't respect those restrictions** when it bounces up from the surface (as demonstrated by the second picture. It rotated around the z-axis, and translated along the Y-axis). What did I overlook?

[image]
[image]

PS: I deleted the file and pictures in my previous question as it was not my own work (though freeware). Didn't feel comfortable with it. This is my own work, so no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Blender Render. Under the "object" tab, you can also fix translation and rotation, but now it will show in the preview animation (see picture). If you press "P" in your screen, you will also see the effect, but then in Blender Game.

[image]